# Missing } inserted. \end{alignat}? why this error keeps on popping up?

Tags: errors, equations, amsmath

here is a part of my code, which I am trying to run.

```
\begin{alignat}{2}
    [M]:   \max_&Z
    ~ \label{eqnP27}\\
    \mbox{s.t.}~
    %capacity constraints
    &   \sum_{k \in H} y_{k} \leq r &&\forall k \in H \label{eqnP28}\\
    %capacity constraints
    &   Z = \min\sum_{i \in N}\sum{j \in N}\sum_{k \in H}\sum_{m \in H} W_{ij}C_{ijkm}X_{ijkm} \label{eqnP29}\\
    \mbox{s.t.}~
    &   \sum_{k \in H} U_{ik} = 1 &&\forall i \in N \label{eqnP30}\\
    &   \sum_{k \in H}U_{kk}  = p - r \label{eqnP31}\\
    &   U_{ik}\leq U_{kk} &&\forall i \in N,\forall k \in H  \label{eqnP32}\\   
    &   \sum\limits_m Y^i_{km} - \sum\limits_m Y^i_{mk} = O_i - \sum\limits_j W_{ij}X_{jk} &&\forall i \in N, k \in H\label{eqnP33}\\
    &   U_{kk}\leq(1 - y_{k}) &&\forall i \in N, k \in H\label{eqnP34}\\    
    &   z_{k}, y_k \in \{0,1\}, \quad Y_{ikm} \geq 0
    &&\forall i,j \in N, k,m \in H \label{eqnP35}
\end{alignat}
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Hmmm... `\max_&`?

Comment: Jep, saw that too, now, you should write `\max_Z&`. Changing that your code compiles in `article` with the `amsmath` package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some things I'd do:

- Equation 1: Replace `\max_&Z ~`  with `\max_Z &` (the `~` isn't needed)
- Equations 2 and 4: replace `\mbox{s.t.~}` with `\text{s.t. }`
- Equation 3: Supply a `_` in front of `j\in N`, to make sure that this string is placed *below* the summation sign
- (3 instances) Omit `\limits` after `\sum`, since you're already in display math mode
- Equations 6 through 9: Supply a few missing `\forall` macros, and use `;` instead of `,` to create more of a distinction between the two sets of `\forall` directives

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
    & [M]:   \max_Z   \label{eqnP27}\\
    \text{s.t. }
    %capacity constraints
    &   \sum_{k \in H} y_{k} \leq r &&\forall k \in H \label{eqnP28}\\
    %capacity constraints
    &   Z = \min\sum_{i \in N}\sum_{j \in N}\sum_{k \in H}\sum_{m \in H} W_{ij}C_{ijkm}X_{ijkm} \label{eqnP29}\\
    \text{s.t. }
    &   \sum_{k \in H} U_{ik} = 1 &&\forall i \in N \label{eqnP30}\\
    &   \sum_{k \in H}U_{kk}  = p - r \label{eqnP31}\\
    &   U_{ik}\leq U_{kk} &&\forall i \in N;\ \forall k \in H  \label{eqnP32}\\   
    &   \sum_m Y^i_{km} - \sum_m Y^i_{mk} = O_i - \sum_j W_{ij}X_{jk} &&\forall i \in N;\ \forall k \in H\label{eqnP33}\\
    &   U_{kk}\leq(1 - y_{k}) &&\forall i \in N;\ \forall k \in H\label{eqnP34}\\    
    &   z_{k}, y_k \in \{0,1\}, \quad Y_{ikm} \geq 0
    &&\forall i,j \in N;\ \forall k,m \in H \label{eqnP35}
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

Comment: HI, thanks for you answer. Can you say me exactly what is the error that I was making ?

Comment: @PrasannaR - The error message was arising because of the item in the first bullet point: Your code had  `[M]:   \max_&Z`, whereas I suggest either  `& [M]:   \max_Z`  (see above) or  `[M]:   \max_Z &`. The `&` symbol indicates the alignment point, and TeX chokes if it's supposed to be in the subscript to `\max`.